# Minecraft Fortune Blocks

Tags: java, minecraft, bukkit

I'm working on a plugin that when you break a block such as stone depending on what level fortune you have on your pickaxe depends on how much it will put in your inventory.

Plugin Details:

- It automatically puts blocks and ores in your inventory
- It automatically smelts ores and blocks

I'm not exactly sure how to make it when a player breaks a block such as stone it will put more then 1 block in their inventory. And what I'm trying to do exactly is if they have lets say fortune 6 on their pickaxe it will put maybe like 5 - 7 blocks in their inventory but if they have like fortune 30 it will put like 10 - 15 blocks in their inventory. I just tried messing around with options and seeing if I could figure it out but I can't figure it out. I don't have any experience with hashmaps either so I apologize if I'm doing them wrong as well.

Code:

```
@EventHandler
public void fortuneBlock(BlockBreakEvent e) {
    Player p = (Player) e.getPlayer();
    Block b = (Block) e.getBlock();

    ItemStack DP = new ItemStack(Material.DIAMOND_PICKAXE);

    if (p.getInventory().contains(DP)) {
        if (DP.containsEnchantment(Enchantment.LOOT_BONUS_BLOCKS)) {
            HashMap<Enchantment, Integer> pickaxe = p.getInventory().getItem(Material.DIAMOND_PICKAXE);
        }
    }
}
```

If you need any other information let me know.

Comment: First off: what version of Minecraft Forge are you using? I can tell it's not up-to-date because it's now `EntityPlayer` and not `Player`.

Comment: @SomePerson I'm using minecraft version 1.10. I'm not using forge I probably should have included this was a plugin not a mod.

Comment: In this a Bukkit plugin then?

Comment: @4castle It is a bukkit plugin yes.

Comment: I'm guessing, you forgot to put `getEnchantments()` after the `getItem` call. All of the information for how to manipulate the player inventory is in the [Javadoc for Bukkit](https://jd.bukkit.org/). I think you will need the [`addItem`](https://jd.bukkit.org/org/bukkit/inventory/Inventory.html#addItem(org.bukkit.inventory.ItemStack...)) method of `Inventory` and also the [`get`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#get(java.lang.Object)) method of `Map`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[getEnchantments()](http://hhttps://hub.spigotmc.org/javadocs/bukkit/org/bukkit/inventory/ItemStack.html#getEnchantments%28%29ttp://)

```
//Map containing all enchantments of the ItemStack
//The Map looks like: [KEY,VALUE]
//  [Enchantment.DURABILITY,2],
//  [Enchantment.LOOT_BONUS_BLOCKS,4]
HashMap<Enchantment, Integer> enchantmentMap = YourItemStack.getEnchantments();
//Check if this map contains the wanted Enchantment
if(enchantmentMap.containsKey(Enchantment.LOOT_BONUS_BLOCKS))
//Get VALUE of KEY which is the enchantLevel "4"
Integer enchantmentLevel = enchantmentMap.get(Enchantment.LOOT_BONUS_BLOCKS);
```

You can imagine a Map like a table, every `KEY` has its own `value`. Wherefore the `KEY` is unique.

Comment: *sorry for late reply* Okay I see exactly what you are doing here. If I could get a quick explanation on how it's working the way it is so I know how to use it in other ways as well. The 

Integer enchantmentLevel = enchantmentMap.get(Enchantment.LOOT_BONUS_BLOCKS);

How does this work to get the level of the enchantment? Like how does it know you are looking for the enchantments level.

Comment: @MrSanfrinsisco Like I said, a Map contains `Keys` and `Values`. Your `Key` is the indicator for the `Value` your want.. with `get(Key)` you somehow ask for the `Value` conntected to this unique `Key`.
A ItemStack can't have a Enchantment twice, so you can get a List with unique `Keys`(Enchantment Type) with theire `Value`(Enchentment Level). In the end a map is just a nice container to store unique data pairs.